# python written code, counting modules and builtin functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is a method to find or count built in functions or imported libraries within written codes.

For example if the codes follow as

```py
import time

start = time.time() 
total = 0
time.sleep(3) 

for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        total += i*(-1)** j
end = time.time() 
print('Program took', end - start, 'seconds.')
```

I wish to count all the built in functions and imported methods
so,

```
library_imported: {time : 1},

library_method : {time: 2, sleep: 1} ,

built-in: {range: 2, print : 1}
```

something like this?

all I can think of is that I would read the written codes as string and
use Counter in collection to count all the words that matches with functions and methods
would there be a better way?